# NameError: name 'onset_to_death' is not defined. Works in Py2 but not Py3

Tags: python, statsmodels, nameerror

I'm taking an online python course (EpiSkills, which uses the Jupyter notebook) that was written in Python 2.7, and I'm on Python 3.6.4 so I have run into a few compatibility issues along the way. Most of the time I've been able to stumble through, but can't figure out this one, so was hoping someone might be able to help.

I start with the following packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import epipy
import seaborn as sns
%pylab inline

import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
```

And use the following code to create a pandas series and model:

```
multivar_model = sm.formula.glm('age ~ onset_to_hospital + onset_to_death + 
        data=my_data).fit()
new_data = pd.Series([6, 8, 'male'], index=['onset_to_hospital', 'onset_to_death', 'sex'])
```

When I try to use this to the following code, I throw the error that I've attached:

```
multivar_model.predict(new_data)
```

[NameError part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fIyH.png)
[NameError part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7IEL.png)

The intended output is meant to be this:

```
array([ 60.6497459])
```

I know that a lot of NameErrors are because something has been specified in the local, not global, environment but I'm unsure how to correct it in this instance. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!
C

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\compat.py in call_and_wrap_exc(msg, origin, f, *args, **kwargs)
    116     try:
--> 117         return f(*args, **kwargs)
    118     except Exception as e:

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py in eval(self, expr, source_name, inner_namespace)
    165         return eval(code, {}, VarLookupDict([inner_namespace]
--> 166                                             + self._namespaces))
    167 

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'onset_to_death' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

PatsyError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-e0364e267da7> in <module>()
----> 1 multivar_model.predict(new_data)

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in predict(self, exog, transform, *args, **kwargs)
    774                 exog_index = exog.index
    775             exog = dmatrix(self.model.data.design_info.builder,
--> 776                            exog, return_type="dataframe")
    777             if len(exog) < len(exog_index):
    778                 # missing values, rows have been dropped

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in dmatrix(formula_like, data, eval_env, NA_action, return_type)
    289     eval_env = EvalEnvironment.capture(eval_env, reference=1)
    290     (lhs, rhs) = _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env,
--> 291                                       NA_action, return_type)
    292     if lhs.shape[1] != 0:
    293         raise PatsyError("encountered outcome variables for a model "

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\highlevel.py in _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env, NA_action, return_type)
    167         return build_design_matrices(design_infos, data,
    168                                      NA_action=NA_action,
--> 169                                      return_type=return_type)
    170     else:
    171         # No builders, but maybe we can still get matrices

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py in build_design_matrices(design_infos, data, NA_action, return_type, dtype)
    886         for factor_info in six.itervalues(design_info.factor_infos):
    887             if factor_info not in factor_info_to_values:
--> 888                 value, is_NA = _eval_factor(factor_info, data, NA_action)
    889                 factor_info_to_isNAs[factor_info] = is_NA
    890                 # value may now be a Series, DataFrame, or ndarray

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\build.py in _eval_factor(factor_info, data, NA_action)
     61 def _eval_factor(factor_info, data, NA_action):
     62     factor = factor_info.factor
---> 63     result = factor.eval(factor_info.state, data)
     64     # Returns either a 2d ndarray, or a DataFrame, plus is_NA mask
     65     if factor_info.type == "numerical":

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py in eval(self, memorize_state, data)
    564         return self._eval(memorize_state["eval_code"],
    565                           memorize_state,
--> 566                           data)
    567 
    568     __getstate__ = no_pickling

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\eval.py in _eval(self, code, memorize_state, data)
    549                                  memorize_state["eval_env"].eval,
    550                                  code,
--> 551                                  inner_namespace=inner_namespace)
    552 
    553     def memorize_chunk(self, state, which_pass, data):

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\compat.py in call_and_wrap_exc(msg, origin, f, *args, **kwargs)
    122                                  origin)
    123             # Use 'exec' to hide this syntax from the Python 2 parser:
--> 124             exec("raise new_exc from e")
    125         else:
    126             # In python 2, we just let the original exception escape -- better

~\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\patsy\compat.py in <module>()

PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'onset_to_death' is not defined
    age ~ onset_to_hospital + onset_to_death + sex
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: try making `new_data` into a one row DataFrame with  column names instead of using a Series with index.

Comment: Thanks @user333700, but I'm afraid that I now get an error saying `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype' `